# Extracting raster values from an RGB

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

I have an RGB raster file and I need to get raster values. How can I extract raster values from this map? I need to reclassify raster according to the pixel value as "very high", "high", "medium", "low"?
[image]

Comment: You cannot classify your RGB raster into "very high", "high", "medium", "low" categories. Such classification is supposed to be performed on single raster layer.

Comment: Try running your data through the isocluster tool with 4 classes?